# Create exe file from script using Pyinstaller in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, pyinstaller, anaconda3

I want to create exe file in Anaconda environment using Pyinstaller.
First, I have successfully installed Pyinstaller using this code:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
```

Then I also have converted my `ipynb` file to py file using "Download as".
Now, when I tried my py code using this code:

```
python Jumlah.py
```

I got his error:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-a5108a3cc2af>", line 1
python Jumlah.py
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

An when I run Pyinstaller using this code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Jumlah.py
```

I got the same error:

```
File "<ipython-input-8-405d6dae7a75>", line 1
pyinstaller --onefile Jumlah.py
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that after downloading the jupyter notebook as .py, your file.py contains lines like "get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')".
You have to delete them first!

Comment: I have checked my py file and there is no such code.

Comment: Can you open Jumlah.py in a text editor and copy paste the first couple lines of code as an Appendix into your question? (Specifically Jumlah.py, not the Notebook)

Comment: This is the first few lines of my py file:Line 1: #!/usr/bin/env python;
Line 2: # coding: utf-8
Line 3: whitespace;
Line 4: # In[1]: . Below these codes are my code. And below my code is this code: # In[ ]: . Sorry, I don't know how to put this code as appendix.

Comment: But the error says: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". So, in my opinion the problem is in the syntax not the content of the py file. CMIIW.

Comment: I tried it myself; and I also get the SyntaxError. It should be due to the SyntaxError in the py file! However, does "python file.py" run without any problems? (Put differently, have you checked your python code if it is without any syntactical errors?)